# Can't view output of command because of incorrect colors

Tags: colors

I am using Ubuntu on WSL and I am trying to get the git status of the current repository.

No issues with the command but I can't read the output text.

If I try to copy the text in those invisible lines, I can do that. I am getting a bunch of filenames in my clipboard which means the text is just invisible.

Can anyone help me reset the colors or something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that from your `.gitconfig`.

You can enter things like:

```
[color]
  ui = auto
[color "branch"]
  current = yellow reverse
  local = yellow
  remote = green
[color "diff"]
  meta = yellow bold
  frag = magenta bold
  old = red bold
  new = green bold
[color "status"]
  added = yellow
  changed = green
  untracked = cyan
```

and choose any colour you want from `normal`, `black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `blue`, `magenta`, `cyan` and `white`.

You can even (optionally) add a second colour as the background; and / or add `bold`, `dim`, `ul`, `blink` and `reverse`.

Taken from https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-colours-in-git/